# Why is this error in blueimp jQuery File Upload: Failed to write file to disk?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am using blueimp jQuery. If I upload a file more than 50 MB, it shows the error: `Failed to write file to disk`.  Why is this happening? My phpinfo setting for `post_max_size` is 1072.

Please help me by showing where I have to change this so that it can allow an upload of at least 100 MB at a time.

Comment: Please check your file permissions

Answer (score 0):

try this in php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize 100M
post_max_size 100M
memory_limit 256M
```

also check

[How to implement file limits](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-implement-File-Limits)

Comment: Hi, these are my settings at present :

`post_max_size = 1072M upload_max_filesize = 1050M memory_limit = 2000M`

Comment: @highlander141 your setting looks fine

Comment: yes then where might be the problem, the link which you gave, i tried it in **upload.class.php** file which performs the form action. But it stated that _php.ini_ settings will take precedence..

Comment: @highlander141 is my answer solved your problem ? please let me know